# how to retain selected value on refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery

```
  (function($) {
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#client-list').change(function() {
           $(this).attr("selected", true);
            location.reload();
        });
    });
});
```

dropdown list

```
  <select id="client-list">
     <option value="Choose-Client">Choose Client</option>
     <option value="client1" >Client 1</option>
     <option value="client2" >Client 2</option>
     <option value="client3" >Client 3</option>
     <option value="client4" >Client 4</option>
  </select>
```

how can i retain selected value and reload the page onchange dropdown?

Comment: Store in `localStorage`.

Comment: what have you tried so far?there are many ways to achieve this goal

Comment: You may find it retains its value on refresh if you add the `autocomplete='on'` attribute.

Comment: Otherwise use cookies or store it on the server side via sessions or simple variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global Variable usage on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload)

Answer (score 0):

Store you values in `localStorage`

First fetch value from `localStorage` and set it as value of your `select`, if it's undefined (when run the first time), it will fall back to first element in your `select`.
If it is defined, then your `select` will have value from localStorage as selected value.

On change, update your value in `localStorage`

```
(function($) {
  const selection = localStorage.getItem('selection');
  $(document).ready( function() {
    let $clientList = $('#client-list');
    $clientList.val(selection);
    $clientList.change(function() {
      localStorage.setItem('selection', $(this).val());
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using cookies in Jquery by using a plugin.

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Download the plugin and include it in your project

```
<script src="/path/to/js.cookie.js"></script>
```

To set cookie

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value');
```

To read cookie

```
Cookies.get('name'); // => 'value'
```

Comment: Please note that this behaviour is not available in base jQuery, as a plugin is needed. --- Also note that this plugin has been replace by another https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie